# how to properly expose an ES class function residing inside a module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a little class for loading a config file:

```
// index.js:

class Config {
    constructor(path) {
        this.path = path || this.defaultPath;
        this.config = fs.readFileSync(this.path, { encoding: 'utf8' });
        this.config = JSON.parse(this.config);
    }
    get() {
        return this.config;
    }
}
Config.prototype.defaultPath = './config/config.json';

module.exports = {
    Config: Config,
};
```

And I test it like so:

```
// test.js: 

const index = require('../index');

let config;

describe('config ', () => {
    before(() => {
        config = new index.Config().get();
    });
});
```

It works, but I'm wary of including a capitalized property in `module.exports` (mostly because I haven't seen this done before). Is there a best practice for achieving this in other ways? Should I just make the config class into its own `.js` file?

Comment: Yes the simple rule is capitalised if the function requires the `new` token to correctly instantiate. Though I would argue that best practice avoids the use of the new `class` token altogether. Also don't use the prototype to store static values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any best practice here, so this answer is my own hunch.

I would stick with using an uppercase 'C' for the exported member name.

In JavaScript, the usual protocol is to use an uppercase name for a function that should be `new` from, rather than called directly e.g.

`function Config()`

to show that the function should be used with a `new` call, to treat it as a constructor. e.g.

`var config = new Config();`

As you are exposing a class from your module, in other words a function that can be new'd up from, then I would stick with using a capital `C`.

Answer (score 1):

> It works, but I'm wary of including a capitalized property in `module.exports`

This is perfectly fine. By convention, constructors and classes use TitleCase, where the first letter in a multi-word name is uppercase while the rest is lower case. Anything else, like variables and functions use camelCase.

Since `Config` is a class, then it makes sense to do so.

> Should I just make the config class into its own .js file?

That depends on preference and use of the module's functionality. In some cases, it makes sense to export just one thing. That way, one file, one responsibility. However, in some cases, you might want to treat modules as a collection of functions.

Both ES6 modules and CommonJS modules do not impose strict rules as to how you export.

Comment: `Config` is not a class, it is an object definition. There is no such thing as a class in Javascript. `class` loosely  refers to an object construction syntax.

Comment: @Blindman67 _"`class` loosely refers to an object construction syntax."_ - which I just did. And I used it to make it distinct from a constructor function that essentially does the same thing, written differently, and which by convention also uses TitleCase.

Comment: I am pointing it out to emphasize that class is syntax in JavaScript and that we should be careful not to infer a paradigm that does not exist. Though to me i am surprised that a "use strict" directive would not enforce "TitleCase" when using `class` as it does make it clear. But then who are we to define nomenclature